# How could cocos2dx render an object which is left the range of design screen?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, game-engine

To trace the character movement, I move the default camera of the scene instead of transforming the coordinate of backgrounds. But I found the character would not be rendered if it has left the range of the range of design screen. Then it would disappear from the screen. How can I solve this problem?

In order to trace the character, I use the code below to move the camera. So the character could be kept in the screen unless it left the range of map. But I found it would not be rendered if it left the design size which I set for this game(eg. The character sprite will disappear when its coordinate is Vec2(960,1200) at the middle of Screen, when I set the design screen of 1920*1080).

```
void GameLayer::moveCamera(cocos2d::Vec2 moveOffset)
{
//get the default camera
auto camera = getScene()->getCameras().at(0);

//calculate targetPosition
auto targetPosition = camera->getPosition() + moveOffset;
float x = MAX(targetPosition.x, visibleSize.width/2);
float y = MAX(targetPosition.y, visibleSize.height/2);
x = MIN(x,mapLayer->map->getMapSize().width * mapLayer->map->getTileSize().width - visibleSize.width/2);
y = MIN(y, mapLayer->map->getMapSize().height * mapLayer->map->getTileSize().height - visibleSize.height/2 );

//set the default camera position
camera->setPosition(Vec2(x, y));
}
```

Comment: Can [edit] this question to add your code in? It makes it easier to debug. Thanks!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I have add the code in.But my English is poor.I hope that I have describe my question clearly enough.